# .py to .exe ISSUE

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a problem with pyinstaller; i have python file (Main_w_PyQt5.py), which uses three pictures (kepler.png; keplerII.png and kepler.ico). I used pyinstaller with these arguments:

`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --icon='kepler.ico' --add-data='kepler.png;.' --add-data='keplerII.png;.' --clean Main_w_PyQt5.py`

The .exe file works great, until i want to close it by calling exit function, window saying "Fail to execute Main_w_PyQt5.py" pops out.

What's the problem with it?

Comment: One: Are you calling `exit`, or `sys.exit` (only the latter is correct; the former is solely for interactive use, and can subtly misbehave when misused)? Two, can you provide a [MCVE] script that reproduces this?

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks! I used only `exit` instead of `sys.exit` , now it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making an answer from [my (confirmed) comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947388/py-to-exe-issue?noredirect=1#comment96657737_54947388):

Don't use `exit`. It's intended solely for use in the interactive interpreter (it's [not even guaranteed to exist since the `site` module is optional](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=exit#exit)), per the docs:

> [These functions/constants] are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs.

Use `sys.exit`, [which is the correct way to signal your intent to exit a script](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

People get lazy and use `exit` because it happens to work in most simple script environments, but PyInstaller is not simple in the least, and using it is causing you problems.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!